# Cant convert an object into an int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with values that should be number. Right now they are an object however:

```
later        object
opstarten    object
dtype: object
```

I have tried to change the column to a str type by doing:

```
df_analyse_num[["later"]] = df_analyse_num[["later"]].astype(str)
```

This does not seem to work however cause when I analyse my types it still says object.

Also when I try to convert it to a string something goes wrong. If I do:

```
df_analyse_num[["later"]] = df_analyse_num[["later"]].astype(str).astype(int)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 937, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas\lib.c:16667)
 File "pandas\src\util.pxd", line 60, in util.set_value_at (pandas\lib.c:67540)
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0'
```

Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Comment: Not an expert on pandas, but try `float` then `int`: `something.astype(str).astype(float).astype(int)`

Comment: Totally works, thanks!

Comment: Firstly `object` refers to the numpy object types this is correct, you will not see `str` as the `dtype` in pandas, secondly if you want to convert your column to numeric use `pd.to_numeric(df_analyse_num["later"], errors='coerce')` this will infer the appropriate type, `int` for where you have no missing values and all values can be converted to `int` without error or float otherwise. Also using double square brackets: `df_analyse_num[["later"]]` returns a single column df rather than a Series in case you didn't know

Comment: You can confirm that the type of the individual elements are `str` by doing `print(type(df_analyse_num["later"].iloc[0]))` this should show `str`

Answer (score 1):

**Not** an expert on pandas, but try `float` first to handle the decimal point which indicates a float, then `int`:

```
something.astype(str).astype(float).astype(int)
```

Here is the problem in "native" python:

```
int('30.0')
```

Which fails similarly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0'
```

If we use `float` first it works since converting `float` to `int` is possible:

```
int(float('30.0'))
```

Expected result:

```
30
```